# Change background color of lighting-Card component

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Probably super easy, but struggling to change the background color of a Lighting-Card. Any Suggestions? I can get it to change in the console by manipulating *element.style*

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <div class="myColor">
        <lightning-card title="Opportunity Relisting" icon-name="standard:channel_program_history">
            <template if:true={opp.data}>

                <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <h1>RELISTED OPPORTUNITY</h1>
                    <p>{name}</p>
                    <p>{relistStatus}</p>
                    <p>{relistDate}</p>
                </div>

            </template>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

**CSS**

```
.myColor.THIS  {
    background: red;

}
```

**Images**

What I'm trying to get is this... 
[image]

This one is the current behavior I have...
[image]

Comment: @martin lezer thanks for the edits.

Comment: I do not think this is an exposed attribute for either Aura or LWC. So your solution of modifying the background via CSS is the only way.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, can you give me a little more insight?

Comment: When looking at the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card/specification, there is no attribute to modify the background color specifically. However, you can specify a custom CSS class like you are doing.

Comment: the issue I'm running into is that the class doesn't seem to change the whole background color. Not sure where to put the class...

Comment: This link may have a solution, https://coderoom.in/apply-css-in-lwc-with-best-possible-way/

Comment: That behavior I have been able to replicate but I'm looking for not just a background color that surrounds the H1 and p elements, but the entire component. Will post an attachment.

Comment: Understood. You may just have to build your own card component manually using the template defined on the SLDS website (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/) and then add an inline style to the `article` element and then expose it as an attribute to modify depending upon your use case

Comment: have you tried overriding the '.slds-card' css class selector?

Comment: Elie, can you provide an example?

Comment: Attempted to use !important, but didn't get the bahvior I was expecting. Could have been using it wrong for LWC.

Comment: The answer to use slots provided by @dhz is by far the simplest approach.  Bonus is it lets you customize where to put buttons and other things!

Answer (score 8):

you can try this, it will work ! :

```
:host {
    --sds-c-card-color-background: #a1d6e4;
}
```

Comment: This worked in Salesforce. It's not working in LWC local dev server though.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to customise lightning-card is passing slots that are styled as you wish, for example:

```
                <lightning-card>
                    <header slot="title" class="slds-page-header slds-page-header_record-home">
                        GroupName 1
                    </header>
                    asdf
                </lightning-card>
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, this does not work: only part of the header has a grey background and the font is not bold.

Answer (score 1):

Bryan Anderson in the comments below should get the credit for this, so feel free to repost Bryan so I can give you the points.

You have to do a manual build of the LWC to get this feature, at least with the knowledge I have, that is what it took.

1. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/

Copy this code:

```
<template>
        <article class="slds-card">
    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
    <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
    <div class="slds-media__figure">
    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="account">
    <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">account</span>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-media__body">
    <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Accounts">
    <span>Accounts</span>
    </a>
    </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-no-flex">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">New</button>
    </div>
    </header>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">Anything can go into the card body</div>
    <footer class="slds-card__footer">
    <a class="slds-card__footer-action" href="javascript:void(0);">View All
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Accounts</span>
    </a>
    </footer>
    </article>
</template>
```

Then mark the 'slds-card' with the background selector and change the color in a CSS file or Inline-Style (didn't try inline but assuming it will work).

I don't like this solution but it appears to be the only way to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just setting the background colour for the card, you can use the :host pseudo class, which targets the shadow host of the shadow DOM.

In the CSS

```
:host {
  --slds-c-card-color-background: var(--c-example-red);
}
```

[Find more info on "Styling Hooks"](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/)